# apt-get install build-essential throws dependency error for libc-dev

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I am not able to install build-essential on Ubuntu Server 14.04. I am getting this error:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential make curl -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                            libc-dev
                   Depends: gcc (>= 4:4.4.3) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: g++ (>= 4:4.4.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but `apt update` should be done before `apt install -f`. Or am I wrong? @George

Comment: @BlueManCZ -- yes it should be first

Comment: Try `sudo apt update`  then  `sudo apt install -f` , followed by sudo apt dist-upgrade